# How can I split a string of names and adjacent numbers, such that the numbers are assigned to each adjacent string name?

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list of NBA teams:

```
teams = ("Los Angeles Clippers","Dallas Mavericks","New York Knicks","Atlanta Hawks")
```

And the results of some matches:

```
results = ("Los Angeles Clippers 104 Dallas Mavericks 88,New York Knicks 101 Atlanta Hawks 112")
```

There are many more names and matches, but for the question I have picked a few.

My question is: how can I split the `results` scores so that the NBA team names are keys and the scores are values? (I am not looking for code as a solution- just an explanation/description)

Here are my thoughts so far, I know how to add the NBA names as keys in the dictionary, but I am struggling with finding a method to assign the numbers to each team in coding terms. I have got as far as using `split()` and splitting `results` at every coma.

I am thinking of then splitting it further, but even if I split each shortened string by name, how can I assign their values next to each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A split wouldn't be very useful, even with a regex, a `findall` would be much easier,

With a pattern like `([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+)` for `team full name score`. I've put the result in a dict by team, but if you have multiple times the same team it'll override as keys are unique, you'll to find another way to store

```
import re

s = "Los Angeles Clippers 104 Dallas Mavericks 88,New York Knicks 101 Atlanta Hawks 112"
results = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+)", s)
print(results)
# [('Los Angeles Clippers', '104'), (' Dallas Mavericks', '88'), ('New York Knicks', '101'), (' Atlanta Hawks', '112')]
print(dict(results))
# {'Los Angeles Clippers': '104', ' Dallas Mavericks': '88', 'New York Knicks': '101', ' Atlanta Hawks': '112'}
```

---

If you want to group by match

```
results = re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+) ([a-zA-Z\s]+) (\d+)", s)
# [('Los Angeles Clippers', '104', 'Dallas Mavericks', '88'), 
   ('New York Knicks', '101', 'Atlanta Hawks', '112')]
```

Comment: Thanks azro- this is so helpful! One question, what does [a-zA-Z\s]+ do? I have used the doc https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions. , but still can't quite understand it. But I do understand (\d+) from the doc

Comment: @PatrickChong the  brackets means "everything inside" so here lowercase, uppercase, space, see https://regex101.com/ it can help